# How to add a fade effect when changing classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I don't know how to add an animation effect when the classes are changed.

**Here is my code:**

```
$("#a-button").click(function() {
    $("#a-div").toggleClass("hidden show");
});
```

This works but it doesn't have any effect when changing the classes.I want to make it smoother, maybe something like fading in and out. How can i do that?

Comment: did you google "jQuery fade in and fade out" ?? because they have methods for exactly that. Also, this would be something you would do by adding css transitions to the element.

Comment: I know, but i coulden't make it interact with the change. It seemed broken

Comment: then at the very least you should post the code you attempted.

Comment: You probably forgot to give a-div a transition.

Comment: $("#other-certs").toggleClass("hidden show").fadeIn('slow');

Comment: You want to show/hide the div with id="a-div" alternatively when clicking thr button

Comment: .fadeIn('slow') doesn't make sense there. don't just sling spaghetti at the wall.

Comment: allright, can you show me how?

Comment: [***"You probably forgot to give a-div a transition."***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39856105/how-to-add-a-fade-effect-when-changing-classes?noredirect=1#comment67000361_39856105)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `fadeOut()/fadeIn()` with `hasClass()` condition to check the if the div has a specific class:

```js
$('.show_hide').click(function() 
{
  if($('#target').hasClass('show'))
    $('#target').fadeOut('normal');
  else
    $('#target').fadeIn('normal');
    
  $('#target').toggleClass("hidden show");
});
```

```css
#target {
  background: green;
  margin-bottom:15px;
  height:150px;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="show_hide">Show / Hide</button>
<div id="target" class='show'></div>
```

Comment: See [THIS](https://jsfiddle.net/k479fbyj/) jsfiddle.

Comment: I saw @RazvanZamfir.. instead of `addClass/removeClass` i prefer to use `toggleClass()` and instead of `:visible` it'll be better to check the class IMO. glad i could helps. Happy coding.

Answer (score -1):

Try this and let me know. It is fadeToggle by jQuery.

```
$("#a-button").click( 
  function() {
    $("#a-div").fadeToggle();
  });
```